# Is Sitecore ASP.NET application or MVC based application?

Tags: sitecore-client

We all know that Sitecore is a web application based on .NET platform. We can develop both ASP.NET as well as MVC based web application on top of Sitecore.

But I am curious to know that as Sitecore is itself a web application, is it developed using ASP.NET or MVC? How can it accommodate both ASP.NET and MVC based web solutions?

Comment: You might find this community post useful: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/how-is-sitecore-mvc-different-from-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @AlexS  .. this link is explaining Sitecore MVC and ASP.NET MVC. However my question is more specific to ASP.NET and MVC.

Answer (score 1):

It is both. Its an ASP.Net MVC application. Although, its use of MVC is not quite the same as building a pure ASP.Net MVC application. But it uses Controllers and Views to build components that are composed together to create the page.

I'm guessing that you really mean, is it ASP.NET WebForms or MVC? To answer that, yes it does support both, but you shouldn't use WebForms anymore, they are going away and lack full support. For example, Sitecore Experience Forms is only supported on MVC and not on WebForms.

The way it supports both, is through the way it renders the page. There are an extra set of pipeline processors that get invoked for MVC renderings that will create the controllers and return the rendered html.

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean it as a ASP.NET and MVC.